# How to close a modal window with Nativescript in Angular?

Tags: android, angular, modal-dialog, nativescript

I have a modal using the modal service:

```
import { ModalDialogService } from "nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs";    
private modal: ModalDialogService,
```

I can call a modal, for example

```
  this.modal.showModal(MyModalComponent, options).then(res => {
      // console.log(res);
  });
```

Now I want to close the modal, but not from within the modal itself. This already works in iOS:

```
        const page = topmost().currentPage;
        if (page && page.modal) {
          page.modal.closeModal();
        } else {
          console.log("error closing modal!!!!");
        }
```

But running this with Android, it will always goes to the error console.log, resulting the modal not being closed. The user can still close it (the modal has a close button), but I also want to programaticly close the modal.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way how you should do it in Angular. Inject `ModalDialogParams` and use the `closeCallback` method.

```
constructor(private modalDialogParams: ModalDialogParams) {}

onCloseButtonTap() {
    this.modalDialogParams.closeCallback();
}
```

Comment: Is this the constructor of my MyModalComponent? Because from the MyModalComponent yes I can close it, but that requires user interaction. I want to close it programmactly. I know have a "fix" with a observable.

Comment: It doesn't need any user interaction. I had placed the code on button click just for demo, the close callback can be called anytime without user interaction.

Comment: Yeah but what I don't see from your code, is that this.modalDialogParams.closeCallback(); called within the the actual modal component  or from the parent. For example I have app.component.ts , there I create the modal with this.modal.showModal (). Now I want to close the modal also from app.component.ts and not from my actual modal component (MyModalComponent)

Comment: In that case use `Injector` get get `ModalDialogParams`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what I ended up doing was implementing an interface to activate the closeCallback on the modal parameters from the other class. Here is a playground showing what I did https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=q1mDZI&v=6